# Check for truthiness without the IF statement

Tags: python

Do other options exist in Python 3? (I am looking for the JS equivalent of `!!var_name`.)

Comment: If you want to get a boolean object that represents another objects truthiness: `bool(myobj)`

Comment: What is wrong with an `if` statement?

Comment: @ppperry Too much writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `bool(obj)` to get an object's boolean truth value.

Comment: Thank you. I have forgotten this global.

Comment: @Vidul `if` is too much writing, but this isn't? Maybe I don't understand your question.

Comment: @erip Because `if` needs body - that simple.

Comment: Things that aren't [falsy](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html)  will be true. Why do you need an actual boolean value?

Comment: @erip _why_: Python testing for `True` / `False` in the shell.

Comment: @Vidul: What do you mean by "Python testing for True / False in the shell", and why is that a thing that needs doing?

Comment: @user2357112 You are asking seriously?

Comment: @Vidul: Yes, seriously. It's really hard to understand what you're saying. Are you talking about examining a Python process's return value from a shell script? Or are you at the interactive interpreter? And why does whatever you're doing need an explicit cast to boolean?

Comment: @user2357112: He's just saying he's using the interactive interpreter and he has some object and he wants to do a quick check whether that object is boolean false.  It's not such a horrible thing to want to do, and he already has two answers for how to do it, so I don't get why you're pursuing this.

Comment: @user2357112 How do you questions relate to my question?

Comment: @Vidul: I'm trying to understand what you want to do in case I can suggest better ways to do it, but your descriptions of what you want to do are confusing.

Comment: @user2357112 Please refrain from labeling my behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

`not not obj_name` works as well